# Knowing if a user picked point is inside or outside a pre-specified area from google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In my application the user chooses two points as **start** and **end**.
Is there any way to customize the google map api so as to know if any of the two places lies inside or outside a pre-specified **Ring-road**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `containsLocation()` method from `Google Maps API`, to detect if point located inside the polygon.

Initialize polygon :

```
var ringRoad= [
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19},
    {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
    {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
];

var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: triangleCoords});
```

Then call:

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latLng, bermudaTriangle)
```

You'll get true if point (latLng) located inside the polygon, and false otherwise. More details you can get from [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation?hl=ru) and [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=ru#containsLocation) documentation articles.